# Reading quantization tables of jpeg files in Java

Tags: java, image-processing, jpeg

I'm searching for a Java library that has an interface for returning DQT of an image. I know that e.g. exiftool can do it, but the Java wrapper does not seem to have an interface for that. Any pointers are appreciated. Some JNI bindings will probably work for me as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the DQTs from the `IIOMetadata` using ImageIO's `JPEGImageReader`.

```
IIOMetadata metadata = jpegReader.getImageMetadata();

IIOMetadataNode root = (IIOMetadataNode) metadata.getAsTree(metadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName());
NodeList dqt = root.getElementsByTagName("dqt");
NodeList dqtables = ((IIOMetadataNode) dqt.item(0)).getElementsByTagName("dqtable");
JPEGQTable[] qTables = new JPEGQTable[dqtables.getLength()];

for (int i = 0; i < dqtables.getLength(); i++) {
    qTables[i] = (JPEGQTable) ((IIOMetadataNode) dqtables.item(i)).getUserObject();
    System.out.println("qTables: " + qTables[i]);
}
```

See [Image Metadata DTD](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/jpeg_metadata.html#image) for docs on what data is available and how to access it.

I've always found the `IIOMetadata`akward and inconvenient, but it does the job (except for some non-spec JPEG files).

If you don't like the API, it's not too hard to parse the JFIF stream and the DQT segments yourself. Inspired by [an old blog post](http://blog.apokalyptik.com/2009/09/16/quality-time-with-your-jpegs/) and some C sample code, I wrote [JPEGQuality](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/imageio/imageio-metadata/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/metadata/jpeg/JPEGQuality.java), that parses the DQT and also tries to re-estimate the quality setting of the JPEG.

Comment: [How can I read JPEG quantization tables on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62516038/reading-quantization-tables-of-jpeg-files-on-android) `javax.imageio.ImageIO` isn't available there.