# How to read a jpeg quantization table?

Tags: linux, image, image-processing, jpeg

How do I extract the quantization coefficients from a jpeg file on Linux?

I know they're in there somewhere!

I see how to get them in Java:  [Reading quantization tables of jpeg files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643218/reading-quantization-tables-of-jpeg-files-in-java)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

djpeg does the trick

```
$ djpeg -verbose -verbose foo.jpg > /dev/null
Independent JPEG Group's DJPEG, version 9  13-Jan-2013
Copyright (C) 2013, Thomas G. Lane, Guido Vollbeding
Start of Image
JFIF APP0 marker: version 1.01, density 72x72  1
Define Quantization Table 0  precision 0
           1    1    1    1    2    3    4    5
           1    1    1    2    2    5    5    4
           1    1    1    2    3    5    6    4
           1    1    2    2    4    7    6    5
           1    2    3    4    5    9    8    6
           2    3    4    5    6    8    9    7
           4    5    6    7    8   10   10    8
           6    7    8    8    9    8    8    8
Define Quantization Table 1  precision 0
           1    1    2    4    8    8    8    8
           1    2    2    5    8    8    8    8
           2    2    4    8    8    8    8    8
           4    5    8    8    8    8    8    8
           8    8    8    8    8    8    8    8
           8    8    8    8    8    8    8    8
           8    8    8    8    8    8    8    8
           8    8    8    8    8    8    8    8
```

Comment: How can I save the output (of the screen) to a file?

Comment: Answering my own comment: You have to redirect the standard output
Something like this, does the trick:
``djpeg -verbose -verbose img.jpg > /dev/null 2> verbose_out.txt``